# How to configure Docker wpdiaries/wordpress-xdebug:latest with VS Code PHP Debug?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I want to configure VS Code Xdebug plugin to work with Xdebug inside a WordPress Docker container.

I have an issue with the ports.

If I specify on the WP-with-Xdebug container in the "ports" section of the docker-compose.yml file:

```
- "9009:9000"
```

And in the environment variable XDEBUG_CONFIG on the same container:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.17.0.1 mode=debug start_with_request=true client_port=9000
```

Then in the launch.json file of the VS Code plugin config I put this line:

```json
"port": 9009
```

Then, when I run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up`, I see that the docker-compose up log is good, no errors are in it. Then I click on the green Play icon before the option "Listen for Xdebug" I get the message box with:

```
listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9009
```

I think that both the WP container with Xdebug in it and the VS Code plugin want to use the same port on the host 9009 to do the same think, send information to one another, but I do not understand why they do not succeed.

I did not put here the output of `phpinfo()` because it contains sensible information.

I use:

1. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug
2. https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug
3. `wpdiaries/wordpress-xdebug:latest` Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/wpdiaries/wordpress-xdebug or https://github.com/wpdiaries/wordpress-xdebug)
4. Xdebug v3
5. latest stable version of WordPress and PHP v8.0.3

I did not try a lot but a little of this: https://github.com/mac-cain13/xdebug-helper-for-chrome and I don't think it helps me in this issue.

This is a filtered version of my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
 
services:
  db:
    container_name: "db_1"
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "wordpress"
      MYSQL_USER: "root"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "9821379"

  wordpress:
    container_name: "wordpress_1"
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wpdiaries/wordpress-xdebug:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "9009:9000"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./html
        target: /var/www/html
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "wordpress"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "root"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "9821379"
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: 'wp_'
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.17.0.1 mode=debug start_with_request=true client_port=9000

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: "phpmyadmin_1"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db:3306
      PMA_USER: "root"
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_PASSWORD: "9821379"

volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

This is my launch.json file:

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9009,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/html"
      }
    },
    // the following is not used and not updated:
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9003
    }
  ]
}
```

Articles I've tried more or less:

1. https://dev.to/natterstefan/docker-tip-how-to-get-host-s-ip-address-inside-a-docker-container-5anh
2. https://dzone.com/articles/setup-wordpress-debug-environment-with-docker-and
3. https://www.wpdiaries.com/wordpress-with-xdebug-for-docker/#using-a-ready-made-image

I've rebooted my laptop and the same issue appears again.

Until I get a reaction to this post I think I will read the docs here: https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug.

Comment: FWIW, the `remote_host=172.17.0.1 ` in the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` line does not do anything with Xdebug 3 anymore, that should be `client_host`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that both the WP container with Xdebug in it and the VS Code plugin want to use the same port on the host 9009

Yes, that nails it on the head. It is *Xdebug* that makes the connection, so there is no reason to expose the 9000/9009 port on the WordPress containers as that is for **incoming** connections. You can remove that expose line.

Comment: I've deleted that expose line and put just this in XDEBUG_CONFIG: `client_host=172.17.0.1 mode=debug start_with_request=true client_port=9000`. It detected some issues in the code (using a $_GET parameter that did not exist) but I put a breakpoint in another file and it is not breaking on it. Can you help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: It seems to work only when using the Chromium extension to enable Xdebug debugging.

Comment: I just had to replace `start_with_request=true` with `start_with_request=yes` in the same string and it seems to work well. Thank you!